# Mapping using an intermediate join table with 2 primary keys

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I fluently map 2 entities that are joined together using a "join" table (it has 2 primary keys).

My entities:

```
Users
Roles
```

Then the 'join' table looks like:

```
RolesUsers
  RoleId
  UserId
```

So I want to query like this:

```
user.Roles
```

Answer (score 1):

In Fluent NHibernate this is achieved by using `HasManyToMany` in your mapping. Ex: (User mapping)

```
 HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
                .Table("RolesUsers")
                .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Inverse()
```